# Unable to extract tar.gz package using Install-ChocolateyZipPackage function

Tags: chocolatey

**Problem**

Extracting a tar.gz package using `Install-ChocolateyZipPackage` results in creation of a file PackageNameInstall containing the directory, while the directory should be extracted.

```
$url = "http://packageName.tar.gz"
$extractionPath = "C:/$packageName"
Install-ChocolateyZipPackage "$packageName" "$url" "$extractionPath"
```

It is possible to include 7zip.commandline as a dependency and subsequently extract the tar.gz package multiple times and removing the downloaded package afterwards.

**Question**

Which Chocolatey function is able to extract tar.gz packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Chocolatey v0.9.10.1+**: Chocolatey's built in [Install-ChocolateyZipPackage](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package) and [Get-ChocolateyUnzip](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-get-chocolatey-unzip) use a vendored 7z.exe full, so they take advantage of the widest amount of formats able to be uncompressed.

**Original Answer**

You can build a dependency on 7z.commandline package and then use it to extract a tar.gz file in the powershell installation steps. There is not a built-in command for this but at least you would have that to move forward right now.

Here's an [example on github](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolateytemplates/blob/master/_templates/chocolatey3/__NAME__.portable/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1#L31):

```
$installDir = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)" 
Start-Process "7za" -ArgumentList "x -o`"$installDir`" -y `"$file`"" -Wait
```

Comment: `Start-Process "tar" -ArgumentList "xvfz -C `"$installDir`" -y `"$file`"" -Wait`, creates a directory but does not extract the tar.gz, while executing `tar xvfz packageName.tar.gz -C c:/temp/helloworld` works

Comment: This currently only works if there is no .tar file in the tar.gz. This [issue](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/386) is open to resolve completely extracting a tar.gz that contains a .tar file.

Comment: You can run get-chocolateyunzip twice though

Comment: @ferventcoder I didn't realize that, thank you. [Here is an example of doing that](https://github.com/Tervis-Tumbler/au-packages/blob/master/kafka/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1#L14)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no built in helper function for extracting anything other than .zip files.  If I had to guess, I would say that this is due to the fact that most archive files, targetted for Windows, uses the .zip format, rather than tar.gz.  The technique that you describe is probably the best approach for doing what you want.

Can I suggest that you raise an Issue on the Github Project page for Chocolatey, to cover a more generic archive extraction helper method?  You can raise this issue here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues

Gary

Comment: Thank you for the advice. [An issue](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/473) has been created.